# Custom radio button with internal circle does not stay centered depending on browser zoom

Tags: html, css

I have a custom radio button style in which there is a colored border with an internal circle to mark a radio button as selected (see picture for an example)

[image]

I've implemented it in the example below. However, what I'm seeing is that at different browser zoom levels, the internal circle does not stay properly centered:

[image] (at 110%)
[image] (at 90%)

Is there a way to make this radio button style stay centered regardless of zoom level? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.radio-label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #4863A0;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.radio-label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #4863A0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4863A0;
}
```

```html
<input class="radio" type="radio" id="myRadio" checked />
<label class="radio-label" for="myRadio">
  Option 1
</label>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @bowlowl Usually Chrome but this happens for Edge and Firefox as well.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce it myself. Have you tried alternative ways of centering, such as using `transform`?

Comment: I have same issue on chrome 118

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to center the inner circle with flex, grid, position:absolute, and to size it by px, percentage, scale... none of them worked. Maybe there's a glitch in pixel computation from browser, resulting in odd numbers?

After some research, using [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient) seems to be more promising, though not perfect. It looks fine on Chrome and Edge but still the same on Firefox.

```css
.radio-label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #4863A0;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}

/* inner circle */
.radio-label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #4863A0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  /* the key is here: */
  background-image: radial-gradient(#4863A0 0%, #4863A0 50%, transparent 55%);
}
```

```html
<input class="radio" type="radio" id="myRadio" checked />
<label class="radio-label" for="myRadio">
  Option 1
</label>
```